# Best algorithm to filter data with multiple criteria in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

I have a multi-dimensional and numerical values only dataset that conceptually look like this:

```
Id   Field1  Field2  Field3  
1    123     .05     10.33
2    234     .17     5.78
3    345     .01     0.23
4    456     .99     1233
...
...
...
```

And I need to retrieve sorted data matching some criteria, like in the following example.

```
select * from data where Field1 > x and Field2 > y ordered by Field3 desc
```

For the filtering clause:

- The conditions can only be Field* "operator" x, where "operator" can be >, <, =, >= or <=, and x can be any number.
- The conditions intersect (i.e., they are connected by AND not OR).
- The "ordered by" field can be any Field*.

What is the best way to implement a data structure and algorithm for the usecase of what I am describing?

Assuming the dataset's size is moderate, under 100k rows.

Here I use SQL syntax to explain what I am trying to achieve. I do not intend to offload the data in SQL. And the dataset does not need to be implemented in a dataframe like data structure in Python. It can be stacks/queues/lists/dictionaries...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla python this can be achieved using [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html?utm_source=djinn) module.

```
from collections import namedtuple

row = namedtuple('Row', ['id', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'])


dset = [
    row(id=1, field1=123, field2=0.05, field3=10.33),
    row(id=2, field1=234, field2=0.17, field3=5.78),
    row(id=3, field1=345, field2=0.01, field3=0.23),
    row(id=4, field1=456, field2=0.99, field3=1233),

]

target = [
    row(id=2, field1=234, field2=0.17, field3=5.78),
    row(id=3, field1=345, field2=0.01, field3=0.23),
]

assert filter(lambda x: x.field1 > 200 and x.field3 < 10, dset) == target
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas to store this as a dataframe and then do this:

```
df = 'Your Data Frame'
new_df = df[ (df['field1']>x ) & (df['field2']>y )].sort_values(by = 'field3')
```